# Pandas Install Error on Mac

Tags: xcode, pandas, installation, pip, cc

When I execute

```
sudo pip install pandas
```

I get the error:

```
creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/pandas/src/datetime

cc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -mno-fused-madd -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -pipe -Ipandas/src/klib -Ipandas/src -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/core/include -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c pandas/index.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/pandas/index.o

clang: error: unknown argument: '-mno-fused-madd' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]

clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future

error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
```

I have installed xcode and xcode command line tools.

In fact, I can confirm that cc is installed by executing:

```
cc -v
```

which returns:

```
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.38) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0
Thread model: posix
```

Comment: Doesn't answer question but I heartily recommend installing via conda (anaconda). http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/

Comment: Macports is also a good option. More updated and flexible than Anaconda, but compiles everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These flags ended up letting me install it:

```
export CFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments
export CPPFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments
```

and then (of course):

```
sudo -E pip install pandas
```

Thanks @user3378649 for the flags suggestion - that got me thinking along the right track!

Answer (score 0):

Can you please these commands for more information.

As long as you didn't mention what you used to overcome this problem, I'd suggest different approaches to help narrow down in order to find the problem:

**First Solution :**
Run these flags :

export ARCHFLAGS="-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future"

if it doesn't work 
run these flags :

export CFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments
export CPPFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments

**Second Solution :**

- Get Homebrew - it's a one-line shell script to install!
- Edit your .profile, or whatever is appropriate, and put /usr/local/bin at the start of -your PATH so that Homebrew binaries are found before system binaries
- brew install python - this installs a newer version of python in /usr/local
- run "pip install pandas"

**Third Solution :**

use easy_install.

Execute the following command in Terminal

```
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin:$(PATH)}"
export PATH
```

Then : 
$ sudo easy_install pandas